# I've changed my display name, but messages in Jobs still show the old one

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, display-names

I've changed my display name in my stack overflow profile.

First I noticed that my developer story on jobs was still showing my old name - but only, when I was not logged in...
So I identified that it also has to be changed in the user story - eventhough it is quite confusing that there are two names.

[image: Display Name and Full name in developer story]

But what is even more strange: The messages in jobs still show the old name.

What can I do about that one?

[image: How my name is shown when answering messages]

Comment: Wait at least 24 hours to give the left hand a chance to talk to the right hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you apply for a job (or when an employer contacts you to gauge your interest about a position) your basic information gets copied into a different table, and when you update your name the information in that table isn't updated. <strike>I'll bring this up internally to better understand if it's a bug or a feature :)</strike> It's a bug, definitely a bug. We'll be fixing it.

In the meantime, I went ahead and manually updated your name on all your applications, please let me know if you find your old name anywhere else.

Comment: ah, thanks for that :-)
okay, so for new messages it should be okay then?

Comment: yes :) if it's not, please let us know. We'll be working on a fix so that no manual intervention is needed in the future