# Name change not propagating to the SO jobs section

Tags: support, status-review, stack-overflow-jobs

I changed my display name everywhere on Stack Overflow, but I still get recruiter messages sent to my old name.  What am I missing?

Also relevant: apparently this account is also associated with my old Gmail account. I think this may be what's confusing the issue.

Both logins point to the correct developer profile, which displays the correct name.

It is still not clear how to resolve.

Comment: Could you mention every place where you change your name, including perhaps [your saved resume](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When editing your Developer Story (e.g. your front piece for Jobs), at the very top section of it you can specify your Display name and Full name, as shown below:

[image: Image showing the Display name and Full name fields and indicating where this content is used]

As indicated in the info block beneath these, your Display name is only used for the public Q&A site, while your Full name is what is shown to employers on our Talent system (while it does say Private Teams, I'm pretty sure the Teams system only looks at your public Q&A profile's Full name field, not the dev story field). Not shown in the above screenshot, there are also checkboxes that appear when you have focus on these text fields that allow you to sync these values to your public Q&A profile's corresponding Display name and Full name fields.

In your case, your Full name field was both not marked to sync with your profile, and contained what I presume to be the incorrect old name that you were receiving messages under. For now I've changed the value to match with your Display name, but feel free to update the value and the checkbox as you see fit.

Comment: Note that while historically, there [have been bugs related to this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/ive-changed-my-display-name-but-messages-in-jobs-still-show-the-old-one), those should be fixed and when I did make the stated change, I confirmed that the change pushed to the tables on the Jobs information table as described.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be it.  My developer story displays my correct name.  Though, I did realize another potential cause -- see edits to the original question.

Comment: I took the liberty of updating your developer story, and can confirm that the table entry on the Jobs side was incorrectly using the old name until said update. The email credential is a unrelated - we do not expose that to employers in any fashion whatsoever, nor make any effects based on it that aren't explicitly authentication related.